# Laravel chaining scopes

Tags: php, laravel, scope, chain

I have a few variables which I am receiving from a POST form, like so:

```
$search = $request->search;
$day = $request->day;
$month = $request->month;
$year = $request->year;
$status = $request->status;
```

In reality I have a bunch more, hence my question. I use these variables to query my database, using scopes. The way I am doing it now:

Chaining scopes:

```
$appointments = Appointment::latest('created_at')->search(search)->day($day)->month($month)->get(); // and so on..
```

But this only works if I use the following scopes:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $date)
{
    if($search)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('start', '=', $date);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because with the above chaining method, if nothing was searched for, and I still directly return the query, no results are found, obviously. I changed my scopes like this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $value)
{
    return $query->whereDate('condition', '=', $value);
}
```

But I would have to do the following in my controller:

```
$appointments = Appointment::latest('created_at');

if($day) {
    $appointments = $appointments->month($day);
}

if($month) {
    $appointments = $appointments->month($month);
}

if($year) {
    $appointments = $appointments->month($year);
}

if($status) {
    $appointments = $appointments->month($status);
}

$appointments = $appointments->get();
```

Yes, this works, but this is silly. Is there any way of doing this which I am not aware of yet? Should I be using a foreach for this instead perhaps or is there a cleaner, laravel way?